# Click and Slide object in Air for Android

Tags: android, flash, flash-cs5

Wondering which gesture to use to be able to allow the user to touch the object with their finger, slide and release the object and allow the object to continue to move across the screen once they release the object.  This would all be in Air for Android as well.  I don't want to move the stage itself, just an object on the screen.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, but you should consider reading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).  It starts like this:

> With the Android drag/drop framework, you can allow your users to move
>   data from one View to another View in the current layout using a
>   graphical drag and drop gesture. The framework includes a drag event
>   class, drag listeners, and helper methods and classes.
>
> Although the framework is primarily designed for data movement, you
>   can use it for other UI actions. For example, you could create an app
>   that mixes colors when the user drags a color icon over another icon.
>   The rest of this topic, however, describes the framework in terms of
>   data movement.

Your question leads me to believe that you need something like this to happen. Hope this helps and sorry if you are asking something different. Cheers